# How to call java method in javascript in sencha?

Tags: java, javascript, sencha-touch

I am new to sencha touch. I want to call my Java method in my .js file. Onclick of the button i want my java method to be called.

The java method I want to call is this:

```
//UserManager.java
public class UserManager extends BaseManager{
...
 public boolean validateUser(String email)
{
    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        result = userDAO.validateUser(email);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(),e.getCause());
    }
    return result;

}
}
```

My sencha javascript file looks like this:

```
{
   xtype: 'button',
   text: 'Login',
   handler: function() {
//something like this i want:
                        //str=UserManager.validateUser('a@gmail.com')
                        //alert(str);
                         if(UserManager.validateUser('a@gmail.com'))
                         polling.Viewport.setActiveItem('QPanel', {type:'slide', direction:'left'});
                        else
                        alert("failed");
                    }
                },
```

Please let me know how do I call the java method inside this javascript in sencha? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in my project(we are using extjs), I am using spring mvc. So, I have all java methods in controller. So, when I need to call it from javascript, we do it through

- Ajax call :

  ```
  Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: 'getCustomerList',
      success: function(result, action){

      },
      failure: function(result, action){

      },
      params: { customerName: Ext.getCmp('name').getValue() }
  ```

  });
- Anchor tag:

  `autoEl:{
      tag: 'a',
      href: 'getCustomerList',
      cn : 'customers'
  }`

in both cases, getCustomerList will map with spring's controller's RequestMapping method.

Comment: Are the java classes that you call in different packages alltogether? What you mean is that all the normal java classes should be kept in container and must be called from there?